# i get the data back from the backend (express.js) but i cannot store it in a state variable

Tags: reactjs, express, graphql

```
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import { getbooks } from "../../GraphQl/Queries";
function BookList() {
  const { error, loading, data } = useQuery(getbooks);
  const [book, setbook] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      console.log(data.books);
      setbook(data.books);
      console.log(book);
    }
  }, [data]);
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="book-list"></ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BookList;
```

here, `console.log(data.books);` is actually working and I get back the list I wanted
but when I try to store it in a state variable, I get back an empty list
how do I rectify this problem pls help

Comment: no code for list [elements] rendering, no code to block rendering during loading, read docs !

Answer (score 0):

Setting the state is asynchronous so you can't log it inside the function right after you set it, you won't see it. So in this case you're actually setting the state after you log it to the console.

Put the console.log outside of your useEffect, you'll see the data.